# How to access foreignkey/ OneToOneField table's data from a ModelForm?

Tags: django, modelform

I have a model called Profile that is related to the User Model. I would like to make a ModelForm for the model Profile. I would like that form to be able to access user's fields.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

address = models.CharField(max_length=250)

contact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):

return self.user.first_name
```

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:

model=Profile

fields=['first_name','address','contact_number']
```

The error shown is

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (first_name) specified for Profile
```

Thank you.

Comment: use ***`user__first_name`***

Comment: you cannot directly add 'first_name' in forms.py you have to add 'user__first_name' instead of 'first_name'.